# How to get informations from lines of a header file

Tags: c#, parsing, split

I have an header file which has a few lines which start with the string #define. Now i need to split these lines to get all necessary information out of it. I could do it with the Split function of string and get the specific string using the index, but i don't think that this is a really safe method.

There are two types of lines, first the "global" lines.

```
#define ERR_CAN_WARNING      ERR ( 0 )  // 0x0001
#define ERR_CAN_ERROR        ERR ( 1 )  // 0x0002
#define STAT_OK             0 // Comment
#define STAT_FAIL           1 // Hardwarefehler
#define STAT_ILL            2 // Kommando-/Parameterfehler
```

What i need from the specific lines:

1. The name after the #define and decide if its ERR or STAT
2. If its ERR then i need the value inside the ERR( ) and if its STAT i just need the value after the name
3. The description of the line which is the text after the //

In Summary i have in this example two kind of lines: Status lines and Error lines.

Now the unit specific lines:

```
#define UNIT_STAT_ARMED        8  // Kommando nicht zulässig, weil CCU armiert ist
#define UNIT_STAT_PULSERR      9  // Fehler in Pulsdefinition
#define UNIT_STAT_SEQERR       0x0A  // Parameter sequence passt nicht zur Pulsdefinition
#define UNIT_ERR_SDC_DSSDN   ERR (8 )  // 0x0100 * SDC Shutdown durch Überstrom während Test
#define UNIT_ERR_SDC_HKSDN   ERR (9 )  // 0x0200 SDC Housekeeping Shutdown
#define UNIT_ERR_SDC_TLMTSDN ERR (10 ) // 0x0400 SDC Shutdown wg Zeitüberschreitung während Test
#define UNIT_ERR_SDC_SYSSDN  ERR (11 ) // 0x0800 * SDC Shutdown wg Anforderung durch CCU
```

What i need from the specific lines:

1. The name of the Unit which is the UNIT after the #define
2. Decide if its ERR or STAT which is indicated after the UNIT
3. If its ERR then i need the value inside the ERR( ) and if its STAT i just need the value after the name
4. The description of the line which is the text after the //

Is there a good way to handle this without using the unsafe Split function because of the use of the possible changing index after splitting the string?

Comment: _... the unsafe Split function ..._ why do you consider it unsafe? I didn't get the reason from your description. Maybe add some code sample to show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Do you actually try to parse the header file to use it in C#? Would this need to be done at compile time or at runtime?